# C# Autofac + AspNetCore слишком быстрое закрытие скоупа во время выполнения асинхронной операции из метода Configure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

Здравствуйте воссоздал проблему, которая у меня проявилась на рабочем проекте.

```
//КЛАСС Startup.cs

public async void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IDataAccessService dataAccessService)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    try
    {             
        await dataAccessService.LongInvoke();
        var disp = dataAccessService.IsDispose; // !!!! true
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
    app.UseMvc();
}

//РЕГИСТРАЦИЯ сервиса

builder.RegisterType<DataAccessService>()
       .As<IDataAccessService>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

//СЕРВИС

public class DataAccessService : IDataAccessService, IDisposable
{
    public bool IsDispose { get; set; }

    public async Task LongInvoke()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        var calc = 5000 + 500;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        IsDispose = true;
    }
}
```

Если в методе `Configure` класса `Startup.cs` на инжектированном сервисе выполнять операцию `LongInvoke`, то `Dispose` внутри dataAccessService вызовется быстрее завершения операции (флаг disp == true).
Сразу после вызова  `await Task.Delay(10000)` в `LongInvoke`, т.е. при возврате потока в пул потоков, сразу же вызывается `Dispose()` в `LongInvoke`.

НО если делать вот так

```
dataAccessService.LongInvoke().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

то все работает, походу я не понимаю разницу, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что метод `Configure` возвращает `void`, то есть вызывающий код не знает, что у вас внутри метода какие то асинхронные манипуляции.

А что делает вызывающий код? Он подготавливает все сущности, что вам для метода нужны, вызывает метод, ждет его окончания и убивает ваши `IDisposable`. Но когда вы используете слово `await` - то синхронная часть метода заканчивается, и в этот момент вызывающий код думает, что метод весь уже закончился, и убивает ваши `IDisposable`, хотя по факту метод продолжает работать, но уже асинхронно (то есть метод возобновит работу после асинхронной операции, хотя для вызывающего кода он уже закончился).

Когда же вы вызываете вашу операцию вот так `dataAccessService.LongInvoke().GetAwaiter().GetResult();` - то это блокирует поток до завершения операции, то есть это НЕ асинхронный вызов. А, так как код у вас становится синхронным (нет операторов `await` в коде, нет асинхронных вызовов в коде), то вызывающий код дождется конца метода и вызовет `Dispose` уже после того, как все закончилось.

Comment: Спасибо, вас понял. Если такой код все равно получается синхронным, то нет смысла в методе Configure использовать асинхронные операции? Например фоновая ининциализация БД, Или еще что то долгое. метод Configure должен использоваться для настройки конвеера обработки запросов, но оттуда приходится вызывать различные фоновые сервисы, правильно ли я делаю или в инфраструктуре Core есть еще способы каких то общих инфраструктурных сервисов?

Comment: @Aldmi где то на гитхабе был тикет для команды asp.net для поддержки асинхронного метода, но что с тикетом сейчас я не знаю. Есть несколько разных хаков, как народ пытается асинхронно запуститься, но я лично просто все асинхронные вызовы делаю синхронными (вот так `dataAccessService.LongInvoke().Wait();`) - это, конечно, не супер эффективно, то метод то вызывается один раз при старте, ну посидит заблокированным поток, зато все стартанет в нужном мне порядке - не вижу тут особых проблем.

Comment: Спасибо! Согласен что не критично, просто хотел разобраться).